# Looking Linux command line with openoffice to convert powerpoint to picture slideshow webpages

Tags: linux, openoffice, microsoft-powerpoint, openoffice-impress

If I do it manually via GUI, I can convert it to 1024x768 resolution.

Is there anyway to convert them to 1920x1080 resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Post it here in case anyone needs it:

http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=7796

I also modify the script a bit to change to the output resolution to 1920x1080 too.  It works beautifully.